# KVM to/from PCs

Tags: keyboard, vnc, remote-control, kvm-switch, video-capture

Is there a way to send keystrokes and mouse signal to a target machine without installing any type of software (even an OS) on the target machine?

I want to do some repair and diagnostics-related (bios-level access) works from outside my workplace.

A partial solution I've figured out: I can log in a machine (let's name it "A") using vnc-like software; this machine will be phisically connected to the target machine ("B"), recieving his video output and sending keystrokes and mouse signal to it via a hardware "thing" that is the target of my question.

I've read of some IPKVM devices, but they're too expensive.

Any homebrew/inexpensive solution? (I like contraptions, also I'm broke).

Comment: there *are* cheap IP KVMs.  The range from single endpoint consumer models to large scale enterprise models.

Comment: You could probably use an IP cam for video\sound and an Arduino with Ethernet  for keyboard\mouse. http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard Est lowest cost: $100 and as a bonus, you can look around your server room remotely.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the Arduino is capable of emulating a keyboard in this way though so I'd definitely verify that you can get that part working first. This would mainly be useful for the BIOS screen. If you're booted up then use RDP or VNC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​. The correct way to do this is:

1. With a proper IP KVM. These are expensive for a reason: only people with a lot of money need them. That's basically it - supply, demand and target market.
2. With remote desktop (Windows) or VNC (any OS with a GUI) or SSH (for command-line *nix). You've already mentioned you can't to this because you want this to work above the operating system.
3. With out-of-band management. For desktop PCs, there is Intel vPro and for servers there's IPMI and their various IP-based KVM's that are built into the OOB management.

Comment: With your first sentence, what do you mean "No" and then saying "The correct way to do this is".   No what?  And if no then what do you mean by "The correct way"? Can you explain how your way is not consistent with what he wants? (I guess you mean that by saying Nope)

Comment: Nope to his actual question: `Any homebrew/inexpensive solution? (I like contraptions, also I'm broke).`